# How to pass a Ruby session variable to a JavaScript tag

Tags: javascript, ruby, tags, haml

I am working with a vendor that uses a JavaScript tag for sale attribution.  I need to pass session variables to the tag.  The tag is firing, and I can see the variables in the logs, but not in the tag.

I verified that the session variable is set by adding `puts{variable}` to the controller and see the proper values in the log, but not able to get the variables in the JavaScript tag.

This is the Tag code:

```
:javascript

  /* Extole Script */
  (function(c,e,k,l,a){c[e]=c[e]||{};for(c[e].q=c[e].q||[];a<l.length;)k(l[a++],c[e])})(window,"extole",function(c,e){e[c]=e[c]||function(){e.q.push([c,arguments])}},["createZone"],0);
  /* End Extole Script */
   extole.createZone({
     name: 'conversion',
     data: {
       "first_name" = <%= fist_name %>,
       "last_name" = <%= last_name%>,
       "email" = <%= email_address>,

     }
  });
```

This is the Controller code:

```
  def index

    if session['cart_products'] == nil
      session['cart_products'] = {}
    end
    puts "\n\nCoupon\n\n"
    puts session['coupon_code']
    puts session['email_address']
    puts session['first_name']
    puts session['last_name']
    puts session['carttotal']
    puts "\n\n"
    @cart_size = session['cart_products'].length

  end
```

The logs show the `session['first_name']` value.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use the same code in the view, for example:

```
"first_name" = <%= session["fist_name"] %>
```

Comment: When I tried this I see this in page source
```
<script>
  /* Extole Script */
  (function(c,e,k,l,a){c[e]=c[e]||{};for(c[e].q=c[e].q||[];a<l.length;)k(l[a++],c[e])})(window,"extole",function(c,e){e[c]=e[c]||function(){e.q.push([c,arguments])}},["createZone"],0);
  /* End Extole Script */
   extole.createZone({
     name: 'conversion',
     data: {
       "first_name" = <%= session["fist_name"] %>,
       "last_name" = <%= session["last_name"] %>,
       "email" = <%= session["email_address"] %>,
  
     }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @kpedrick1 I meant in the index.js.erb or index.json.jbuilder view that contains the code which will be rendered

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using HAML for your template (judging by the `:javascript` filter), but you're trying to use ERB interpolation inside.

You need to use proper HAML interpolation:

```
:javascript

  /* Extole Script */
  (function(c,e,k,l,a){c[e]=c[e]||{};for(c[e].q=c[e].q||[];a<l.length;)k(l[a++],c[e])})(window,"extole",function(c,e){e[c]=e[c]||function(){e.q.push([c,arguments])}},["createZone"],0);
  /* End Extole Script */
   extole.createZone({
     name: 'conversion',
     data: {
       "first_name" = '#{fist_name}',
       "last_name" = '#{last_name}',
       "email" = '#{email_address}',

     }
  });
```

The surrounding single quotes are there for JS to interpret these as strings.

Documentation: https://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby-interpolation-